# Getting a more useful/accurate error message

Tags: ms-access, vba

We have an issue with an Access front-end that seemingly randomly but constantly times out users with no explanation. This has been a long-standing issue, each time the disconnect happens we're provided with the sub that's causing the issue and a generic error message.

I'm starting to think the error message is misleading, it gives a generic "Connection Failure" with an Error Code of 0. After Googling the code that apparently means no error occurred?

I use C# not VBA so I'm not familiar with it but the error handling is as follows:

```
    Private Sub Form_Timer()

    Dim blnSystemMaintenance As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrHand

    ' Check for System Maintenance.
    blnSystemMaintenance = DLookup("SystemMaintenance", "ConfigItems")
    If blnSystemMaintenance Then

    //Do stuff
        Else
    //Do stuff
        End If

    //Do stuff

    End If

    ErrExit:
        Exit Sub
        Resume
    ErrHand:
    '    If Err.Number = 1 Then

    '    Else
            MsgBox "Error number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, _
           "Unexpected Error Occurred in Sub: Form_Timer"
    Resume ErrExit
    '    End If


    End Sub
```

Is there a way to get a more helpful error message?

Comment: You can put line numbers into it but it's quite complicated.

Comment: What do you mean by line numbers? As in returning the error line? I was hoping more for some kind of proper exception message rather than just "Connection failure"

Comment: If your code calls other procedures, all those procedures also should have error handlers, otherwise, the error from those procedures will be "bubbled" upper until code with error handler reached and error code/message will be totally misleading.

Comment: It opens another form, however each sub in the form it opens has its own error message informing the user which sub failed so I think it should be ok there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain aggregates often don't give descriptive error messages. I'm assuming your database runs into problems connecting to the backend when running the domain aggregate.

You can easily replace your domain aggregate with a recordset call:

```
blnSystemMaintenance = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT SystemMaintenance FROM ConfigItems")(0).Value
```

Often, those give a bit more descriptive errors, if the error occurs at all when using a recordset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, frustratingly I can't just change it and test it directly myself so I'll have to put in a request and see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes error messages may be misleading for some type of functions like `DLookup`, this is a system problem, but sometimes error messages are misleading because not all procedures have correct error handlers and it's difficult to localize the problem especially if the developer has no direct access to the application. So, correct error handlers may significantly simplify troubleshooting.

Normally I use two types of error handlers, which give me quite clear diagnostic messages. Most common - usual error handler for procedures, which may interact with the user and normally called by the system - events handlers:

```
Private Sub Frame2_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    'code here
ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
    Resume '>> remove in release
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & err.Number & " (" & err.Description & "), Line " & Erl & " in procedure Frame2_Click of Form_Form1", vbExclamation + vbMsgBoxHelpButton, "Error " & Now()
    Resume ExitHere
End Sub
```

The second type of handlers - for procedures, which may be called only by other VBA procedures, "bubble" handler, which adds information about the error to error description and passes the error up to caller procedure:

```
Sub MySub()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    'code here
ExitHere:
    Exit Sub
    Resume '>> remove in release
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Assert Not (STOP_AT_ERROR And IS_DEV) '>> remove in release
    err.Raise err.Number, "MySub of Form_Form1", err.Description & vbCrLf & "in MySub of Form_Form1 at " & Erl
End Sub
```

It allows to show full call stack with error lines and procedure names. Line numbers should be added to each line of code though.

For debug simplifying I use two constants: if `STOP_AT_ERROR` is `True` and `IS_DEV` is `True`, code execution stops right after the error without bubbling and allows to inspect variables. For inspecting, I move the code execution pointer to the line `Resume` using Ctrl-F9, then press F8 and code pointer moves to the row, which caused the error.

In the production or QA versions just change `IS_DEV` to `False` and code won't stop at `Debug.Assert` line.

For automatic generating error handlers and adding line numbers, I use third party software, for instance, MZ-Tools. It can be done manually, but it's quite a time consuming

Comment: The general point of this question is fine (nice error handling code!), but afaik it doesn't apply to this case because it's a rare type of error that can't be generated by err.Raise: the err.Number is zero, while the err.Description is set! That's a scenario that should never happen (and if it does, your second error handler will fail with RTE 5 Invalid procedure call or argument). I think I've previously encountered it when having connectivity issues to my backend, but note this special kind of error will make your error handler fail.